# Cannot Find Div Tag using selectors in R

Tags: r, css-selectors, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to access data inside several different websites using the rvest package. On one page such as:

http://www.superiorlivestock.com/onlineCatalog/?auctionId=1098&lot=129762&lotIndex=1

I cannot access the div tag

```
<div class="detailLotHeader">
```

This tag contains the text title for each lot. I tried code such as:

```
home = html("http://www.superiorlivestock.com/onlineCatalog/?auctionId=1098&lot=129762&lotIndex=1")
nodes = home %>% html_nodes("div.detailLotHeader")
```

However, I didn't get any nodes in return. I have been able to access other divs in a similar way. What is going wrong?

Comment: Restart `R` and run again. I was able to run your code.

Comment: I restarted R and cleared my workspace. The code runs without errors its just that I get a list of 0 nodes when I expect at least 1.

Comment: I don't get what you are saying. But, this is what I got`[[1]]
<div class="detailLotHeader" style="padding-bottom:10px;">&#13;
&#13;
       <h2>Lot # 3650&#13;
&#13;
&#13;
                 --  SOLD $286.00&#13;
&#13;
&#13;
 &#13;
       </h2> &#13;
       <span>Arch Diamond Dairy</span><br /></div> `

Comment: I switched to another computer for work and now the code works as I had written it. This is very strange perhaps it is an issue with the version of R?